# Does GNU make suffer from race conditions when building targets that have common dependencies?

Tags: makefile, race-condition, gnu-make

I have a simple example makefile that shows my problem:

```
.PHONY: a.out b.out

all: a.out b.out

common:
    echo building common
    sleep 1
    touch common

a.out: common
    echo building a.out
b.out: common
    echo building b.out
```

a.out & b.out depend on common, so there can be a race condition (common being generated twice) when doing a parallel build.

I did make -j4 and didn't experience common being generated twice. I even put a sleep statement in the generation of common to make things more deterministic.

So is it safe to say that GNU make properly synchronizes when building common dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, GNU make's parallelization support handles this properly (it would not be very useful if it didn't!)  In general, *if* your makefile environment completely and correctly declares your dependency graph to make, then make will always build it correctly regardless of the number of parallel jobs.

The trick is that for some kinds of complicated environments, it can be difficult to completely and correctly declare the dependency graph.  But for simple situations like above, there's no problem.

Comment: Good. Thanks for confirming.                                                  "it can be difficult to completely and correctly declare the dependency graph"          I think you mean recursive makefiles (yuck). I have a couple of those, so I still might have to deal with problems. But I have already dealt with it in the past: do a 2 stage make:  (stage0: commonDependency    make stage1)                    Is there a better way?

Comment: Without details it's impossible to say if there's a better way.  There are a number of advanced features of make, such as order-only dependencies, which might or might not help you depending on your situation.  Also, while recursive makefiles are one complication they're not the only one: recipes that have multiple output files (particularly if the output filenames are not related) are tricky, and there are other complicated dependency relationships which can be hard to model.

Comment: Note that GNU make does *not* handle the case where the recipe for `common` in your example creates a file called `common` before filling it with content. This can happen if you redirect the output of a command to a file, since an empty file gets created immediately. I found this out the hard way :(

Comment: I don't understand your comment, Collin.  Make doesn't poll the filesystem to see when a target is created before starting new jobs; it waits for the recipe to complete.  It doesn't matter to make whether the first line or the last line in your recipe creates the target; make won't start any targets that depend on it until the last line of the recipe exits.

Comment: @MadScientist: Now that I look into that issue in more detail, I think it may have been a side-effect of not normalizing all my paths. I think GNU make did not recognize that `../cwd/file` was the same target as `./file`.

Comment: It certainly will not do that; GNU make uses string comparison of target names for target matching, not absolute paths (many targets are not files and don't have paths) or inodes or some other low-level filesystem invariant to see if targets are the same.  The only exception is GNU make has special handling of `./`, so `./foo` and `foo` are treated as the same target.